# Is there a way to quickly make all photos in a onenote notebook searchable?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-onenote

For instance I have a notebook filled with scans of documents that i need to be searchable, but I don't have the time to right click them all and manually make them searchable.

Comment: I believe there is an option in OneNote's settings to make all images searchable by default.

Answer (score 0):

Images are recognised and indexed automatically. You don't need to do each individually. It is very effective, even recognising sideways text and text in poor quality images. But it isn't perfect, especially on longer texts.

Only video and audio file indexing needs turning on separately and you can only do that in the full version of OneNote not that universal app designed for tablet mode and phones.

The only other control is in Indexing Options (part of Control Panel). There you can turn off OneNote indexing totally which should stop Windows recognising
text in OneNote images.